# Bootstrapのdatatables内におけるselectボックスにデータを挿入するには

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

JqueryとBootstrap、Javaで開発しています。
今回datatables内にセレクトボックスを設置しているんですが、データの入れ方がうまくわかりません。
わかるかたいましたら、ぜひご教授お願いいたします。

##### HTML部分のコード

```
<table id="kategoriTanka" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped center-all">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:25%; text-align:center;" >カラムA</th>
      <th style="width:25%; text-align:center;" >カラムB</th>
      <th style="width:50%; text-align:center;" >リストA</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

##### データテーブル部分のコード

３つ目の行のLISTAの部分にセレクトボックスを表示してデータテーブルにデータを入れたいと思うんですが、データテーブル内の記述とデータの入れ方がよくわかっていません。

```
      $('#tbl').on('processing.dt', function (e, settings, processing) {
          toggleBoxOverlay(processing);
        }).DataTable({
          lengthChange: false,
          displayLength: "All",
          sort: false,
          info: false,
          paging: false,
          responsive: true,
          ajax: {
            url: '/xxx/xxx',
            type: 'GET',
            data: function (param) {
              var ID = $('#ID').val();
              param['ID'] = ID;
              return param;
            }
          },
          columns: [
            {
              data: 'ColumnA',
              render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
              return "<input class='form-control' id='ColumnA' maxlength='50' type='text' value='" + nullToSpace(data) + "'>";
              },
            },
            {
              data: 'ColumnB',
              render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
              return "<input class='form-control' id='ColumnB' maxlength='50' type='text' value='" + nullToSpace(data) + "'>";
              },
            },
            {
              data: 'ListA',
              render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
              return "<select class='form-control' id='ListA'>"
                 + "</select>";
              },
            },
        ],
      });
```

Comment: datatablesとはjQuery pluginの[datatables](https://datatables.net/)のことでしょうか？html、jsともに関連のあるコードをすべて載せてもらえますか？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。
本文に追加いたしました。

Comment: ListAにどんなデータが来て、どんな形で option を生成したいのでしょうか。

Comment: ListAにはリスト型のオブジェクトを入れたいんですが、datatablesにそのまま入るのかがよくわかっていません。
最終的には<option value="***" > -----</option>の形で表示してドロップダウンの形で表示したいです。

Comment: 配列のことですか？ajax で返ってきたデータに対して columns にどう入るかは[ここ](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax#Column-data-points)を見てください。また、ajaxで返ってくるデータの例を追記していただけますか。

Answer (score 1):

`ListA`の`render`にて`<option>`を含んだ`<select>`の文字列を返せばいいのでは？

とりあえず`ListA`に配列が来ると仮定してデモを作りました。

```js
$('#tbl').DataTable({
   searching: false,
   sort: false,
   paging: false,
   data: [
     {ColumnA: 3, ColumnB: 12, ListA: [1, 3, 4]},
     {ColumnA: 6, ColumnB: 2, ListA: [10, 3, 1]},
   ],
   columns: [{
     data: 'ColumnA',
     render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
       return "<input class='form-control' id='ColumnA' maxlength='50' type='text' value='" + data + "'>";
     },
   }, {
     data: 'ColumnB',
     render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
       return "<input class='form-control' id='ColumnB' maxlength='50' type='text' value='" + data + "'>";
     },
   }, {
     data: 'ListA',
     render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
       var html = "";
       html += "<select class='form-control' id='ListA'>";
       for (var val of data) {
         html += "<option value='" + val + "'>" + val + "</option>"
       }
       html += "</select>"
       return html;
     },
   }, ],
 });
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:25%; text-align:center;">カラムA</th>
      <th style="width:25%; text-align:center;">カラムB</th>
      <th style="width:50%; text-align:center;">リストA</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Karamarimoさんのdemoを参照させていただいたおかげで、解決しました！
初めてこのサイトを利用させていただいたんですが、本当に助かりました。
わざわざありがとうございました。